# How to synchronize time on virtual linux server running occasionally?

Tags: centos, virtualization, time-synchronization

I have following setup for web development:
Windows laptop with Microsoft Virtual PC 2007, in it i have Centos virtual machine.

Problem i have is that every time when laptop goes to sleep with virtual machine running or every time i close virtual machine using Save state and then start it again it is stuck with time before it went to sleep.

If i restart OS in virtual machine is syncs its time with host operating system, what i also want to add it ability to do it regularly to avoid time drift.

Comment: I so want to be able to fix this question.

Comment: Brad, is it better now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ntpdate, which may be in /usr/sbin or /sbin:

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

For more info try:

```
man ntpdate
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Alexeit, it may be a good idea to edit your title - change "synchtonise" to "synchronize" so that Googlers can find it. :)

Comment: thanks for answer, i used both of them to figure out how to sync time, debug why it was not working (firewall issues, man helped) and how to set it to run

Answer (score 1):

try running ntpdate when you bring the server up, or run it every 15 minutes out of cron:

(eg */15 * * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate)

Comment: thanks for answer, i used both of them to figure out how to sync time, debug why it was not working (firewall issues, man helped) and how to set it to run